# Woocommerce Order Details Not Loading Properly

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I am using WooCommerce Print Invoices & Packing Lists Plugin. I want to add some custom field values in the order invoice. But the fields are not loading properly.

```
add_action('wc_pip_after_body', 'dvsi_invoice_footer');
function dvsi_invoice_footer ($order_id) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    echo '<h4>'.__('Name: ').'</strong> ' . $order->billing_first_name . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>'.__('Note: ').'</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'public_details_new', true ) . '</h4>';

    ?>
    <h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;">Important:</h4>
    <p>If you have purchased Domain, Hosting, SSL certificate or any other service that has an Expiry date then please contact us 10 days before prior to the Expiry date so we can renew or repurchase it on time.<p>                      
    <h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;">Contact Details</h4>
    <p><strong>Office: </strong>AL-Hafeez Heights Gulberg III, Lahore<p>
    <p><strong>Mobile: </strong>0323-4152099<p>
    <p><strong>Email: </strong>contact@devsol.pk<p>
    <?php   
}
```

The output didnot load my custom field values and display blank. It only load html values.

[image]

Here is the link of the available plugin hooks: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoices-packing-lists-developer-reference/#section-1

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `$order_id` argument for [`wc_pip_after_body`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoices-packing-lists-developer-reference/#wc_pip_after_body) hook, but the following arguments are available: `$type`, `$action`, `$document` and `$order`.

So you can use it this way in your code *(assuming that `public_details_new` custom field exits)*:

```
add_action('wc_pip_after_body', 'dvsi_invoice_footer', 90, 4 );
function dvsi_invoice_footer ( $type, $action, $document, $order ) {

    echo '<h4>'.__('Name: ').'</strong> ' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '</h4>';
    echo '<h4>'.__('Note: ').'</strong> ' . $order->get_meta( 'public_details_new' ) . '</h4>';

    echo '<h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;">'.__('Important: ').'</h4>
    <p>'.__('If you have purchased Domain, Hosting, SSL certificate or any other service that has an Expiry date then please contact us 10 days before prior to the Expiry date so we can renew or repurchase it on time.').'<p>'; 

    echo '<h4 style="margin-bottom:0px;">'.__('Contact Details: ').'</h4>
    <p><strong>Office: </strong>'.__('AL-Hafeez Heights Gulberg III, Lahore').'<p>
    <p><strong>Mobile: </strong>'.__('0323-4152099').'<p>
    <p><strong>Email: </strong>'.__('contact@devsol.pk').'<p>'; 
}
```

It should better work.

**Note:** As @helgatheviking said `WC_Order` Object properties are not anymore accessible since Woocommerce 3, and you need to use [the corresponding available methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this solves the issue, but need to use the WooCommerce CRUD getters.

```
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
echo '<h4>'.__('Name: ').'</strong> ' . $order->get_billing_first_name() . '</h4>';
echo '<h4>'.__('Note: ').'</strong> ' . $order->get_meta( 'public_details_new', true ) . '</h4>';
```

Direct access of object properties has been deprecated for a few years now and at least is throwing lots of warnings.

You may also need to verify that your custom meta is being saved correctly.

Comment: Its not working. Can you please check the hook link please: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-print-invoices-packing-lists-developer-reference/#wc_pip_order_details_after_customer_details

Comment: Looks like Loic's got you. Per the docu you sent, `$order_id` is not the first parameter passed via the hook.